# Directory Listing error ONLY in port 22 (SFPT)

Tags: ssh, sftp, ls, cyberduck

I suddenly get this error using **SFTP**:

```
Status: Connecting to 64.207.146.82...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "root@64.207.146.82" 22
Command:    Pass: *********
Status: Connected to 64.207.146.82
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    pwd
Response:   Current directory is: "/root"
Command:    ls
Status: Listing directory /root
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I tried using **FileZila**, **Cyberduck**, **Shell** (Terminal), same result. However, it worked fine today (just a few seconds) in **Passive** mode.

This is the message in **Cyberduck**:

```
I/O Error: Unexpected end of sftp stream.
```

I have no firewall active on my computer, and after changing some things in my network I pass the test (both active and passive):

```
Connecting to probe.filezilla-project.org
Response: 220 FZ router and firewall tester ready
USER FileZilla
Response: 331 Give any password.
PASS 3.6.0.2
Response: 230 logged on.
Checking for correct external IP address
Retrieving external IP address from http://checkip.dyndns.org:8245/
Checking for correct external IP address
IP 186.15.222.5 big-bf-ccc-f
Response: 200 OK
PREP 50185
Response: 200 Using port 50185, data token 386379933
PORT 186,15,222,5,196,9
Response: 200 PORT command successful
LIST
Response: 150 opening data connection
Response: 200 Successful
QUIT
Response: 200 goodbye!
Connection closed
```

Now I'm working on **Passive** mode.

Because I'm working behind a router, I get my external IP from http://checkip.dyndns.org:8245/

I tested different range of ports.

**SSH is working perfect, but SFTP gets stuck in the listing directory part.**

```
sftp root@64.207.146.82
root@64.207.146.82's password: 
Connected to 64.207.146.82.
sftp>ls
```

Doing some debugging from ssh:

```
ssh -vv root@domain.com
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to domain.com [64.207.146.82] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 128/256
debug2: bits set: 543/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'domain.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Admin/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: bits set: 508/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@domain.com's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to domain.com ([64.207.146.82]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Fri Dec 21 19:55:45 2012 from ip5-222-15-186.ct.co.cr
############################################################
                     (mt) shortcuts
############################################################

To see your Plesk password, type: p

To rebuild your Apache/Web Server configuration, type: web

To rebuild your Qmail/Mail Server configuration, type: mchk

To see your Qmail/Mail Server queue, type: q

To completely restart your Qmail/Mail server, type: r

To connect to your MySQL server as admin, type: my

To apply the latest Plesk microupdates, type: up

To get rid of these messages/aliases, edit your /root/.bash_profile

[root@domain ~]#
```

**SOLUTION**:

Once you login/connect with the server using SSH:

```
p link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue 
    link/void 
[root@domian ~]# ip link set eth0 mtu 1400
SIOCSIFMTU: No such device
[root@domian ~]# ip link set venet0 mtu 1400
[root@domian ~]# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc noqueue 
    link/void 
[root@domian ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use rsync instead?

```
rsync -avP -e 'ssh -l <username>' <host>:/<directory_to_copy> <where to copy it to locally>
```

Try scp as well:

```
scp user@host:/dir_to_copy where_to_copy_it_to
```

Comment: with rsync 'receiving file list ...' (nothing happened) With scp 'cp: /Users/Admin/ is a directory (not copied).'

Comment: Can you show me your commands?

Comment: which ones my friend?

Comment: Any command you are using that work or do not work... I can't help you unless i know what you're doing.

Comment: Ah, here is the problem: "To get rid of these messages/aliases, edit your /root/.bash_profile"

Open /root/.bash_profile and comment out anything that starts with 'echo'.

Alternatively just rename .bash_profile to any other name... but it might have some commands in it that you need to make your environment work.

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I edit /root/.bash_profile ? I tried using ssh and connecting with the server, but if I write: /root/.bash_profile it answer: -bash: /.bash_profile: Permission denied

Comment: You probably shouldnt be digging this deep then, but the safest bet for you would be to ssh in and type:
mv /root/.bash_profile /root/bash_profile_backup

Comment: Thank you @Alives, the solution was lower MTU to 1.400, I updated my question.